# HTTP 200 Instead of HTTP 301 in Post Request (Django Unittest )

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, http-post, http-status-code-301

I am writing unit tests for my Blog application. One of my post request tests constantly gets a HTTP 200 result although I expect HTTP 301. Here is the test code:

```
def test_create_user_post(self):
    response = self.client.post("/create_user/", {
        "user": self.user, "full_name": "Test User", "location":
        "Istanbul", "age": 26
    })

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 301)
```

The create user view creates a new user with a user foreign key. Here is the `UserProfile` model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug_name = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    profile_pic = StdImageField(
        upload_to='images/profile', blank=True, variations={'thumbnail': (450, 300)})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug_name = slugify(self.full_name)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And below is the `create_user` view:

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(
            request.POST, initial={'user': request.user.username})
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/blogs/")
        else:
            form.non_field_errors()
    else:
        form = UserForm(initial={'user': request.user.username})

    return render(request, "BlogApp/create_user.html", {"form": form})
```

My other post requests without user are returning a 301 response, I am suspicious about it. Here is an another post request test example which works properly:

```
def test_comment_post_in_blog(self):
    response = self.client.post("/blog/11", {"comment_text": 'This is a '
                                                             'test '
                                                             'comment.'})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 301)
    self.assertEqual(response['Location'], "http://testserver/blog/11/")
```

I couldn't find the problem, and I hope I explained it clearly. Hope to hear some answers from you guys!

Comment: Sounds like your form is invalid for some reason. Did you try to print the response to look at the invalid fields? (I’d bet on `"user": self.user` taking over `initial={'user': request.user.username}`)

Comment: Note that `form.non_field_errors()` on a line by itself does nothing at all; Python is not Ruby, you need to explicitly return things. But the code would be fine without that else block anyway.

Comment: When I printed out the response it brings me html output and one of the line says that :                                                                                         <tr><th><label for="id_user">User:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul><select id="id_user" name="user">

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for the useful advice!